# another LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

I'm automating a pdf report using rmarkdown.  I use a macro to run the code.  I can run the code once and it works with no problems. When I call the macro again, it appears to work but when creating a pdf, I get the error "LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}"

This is what I get the first time:

```
output file: L:/Statunit/morton/NCC R markdown reports/NCC Reports/NCC_Dashboard_Report_Dave.knit.md

"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS "L:/Statunit/morton/NCC R markdown reports/NCC Reports/NCC_Dashboard_Report_Dave.utf8.md" --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc9e03c3032cf.tex --template "C:\Users\Mortond\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine xelatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in" --variable "compact-title:yes" --include-in-header "C:\Users\Mortond\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8cWvvQ\rmarkdown-str9e022b75c22.html" 

Output created: Report-254-225573.pdf
```

The second time, I call the same code but only change the report name, so the data is the same and I get.

```
output file: L:/Statunit/morton/NCC R markdown reports/NCC Reports/NCC_Dashboard_Report_Dave.knit.md

"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS "L:/Statunit/morton/NCC R markdown reports/NCC Reports/NCC_Dashboard_Report_Dave.utf8.md" --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc9e01f0a74c5.tex --template "C:\Users\Mortond\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine xelatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in" --variable "compact-title:yes" 
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Error: Failed to compile Report-253-225573.tex. See Report-253-225573.log for more info.
```

my YAML is

```
---
    title: ''
    header-includes: 
    - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    - \addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm} % make more space for the header
    - \pagestyle{fancyplain} % use fancy for all pages except chapter start
    - \lhead{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{TJC_logo_color.png}} % left logo
    - \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove rule below header
    output:
       pdf_document: 
       latex_engine: xelatex
       word_document: default
       html_document: default
       urlcolor: blue
       classoption: landscape
---

my code that calls the markdown is :
    render_report = function(b,h,p) {
      rmarkdown::render(
       "L:/Statunit/morton/NCC R markdown reports/NCC Dashboard Report 
          Dave.Rmd", params = list(
          b1 = b,
          h1 = h,
         p1 = p
        ),
        output_file = paste0("Report-", h, "-", p, ".pdf")
      )
    }

    render_report(b="xxxx Hospital, Inc.",h='253',p='225573')
```

The log file with the error part is.

```
("C:\Users\Mortond\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\xet
ex.def"
File: xetex.def 2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen160
\Gin@req@width=\dimen161
)
("C:\Users\Mortond\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grffile
.sty"
Package: grffile 2017/06/30 v1.18 Extended file name support for graphics (HO)
Package grffile Info: Option `multidot' is set to `true'.
Package grffile Info: Option `extendedchars' is set to `false'.
Package grffile Info: Option `space' is set to `true'.
Package grffile Info: \Gin@ii of package `graphicx' fixed on input line 494.
)
("C:\Users\Mortond\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\parskip\parskip.
sty"
Package: parskip 2018-08-24 v2.0a non-zero parskip adjustments
)
("C:\Users\Mortond\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\titling\titling.
sty"
Package: titling 2009/09/04 v2.1d maketitle typesetting
\thanksmarkwidth=\skip53
\thanksmargin=\skip54
\droptitle=\skip55
)
("C:\Users\Mortond\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fancyhdr\fancyhd
r.sty"
Package: fancyhdr 2017/06/30 v3.9a Extensive control of page headers and footer
s
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip56
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip57
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip58
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip59
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip60
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip61
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip62
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip63
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip64
)

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.90 \addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm} \%
                                         make more space for the header 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 22493 strings out of 427767
 408844 string characters out of 3146884
 530389 words of memory out of 3000000
 26423 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 532722 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 45i,0n,68p,816b,443s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

No pages of output.
```

So why does it work once and not a second time?  If I exit RStudio and then s start it up again, it appears to work.  I've tried to
    `.rs.restartR()`    to no avail. as well as 
    `rm(list = ls(envir = globalenv()),envir = globalenv())`
    `gc()` to clean things up.

Any thoughts?  I appreciate reading through all this.

Comment: I may have found the solution through a different type of error.  I tried detaching kableextra via  ` detach("package:kableExtra", unload=TRUE)`   and was able to generate 2 reports int he same session.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I had the same issue. But I experienced that if I compiled my document it worked the first time and failed the second. I suspected a cache issue and added `cache.rebuild=T` to

`` <<echo=F, cache=T, message=F, warning=F, `>>=
set_parent('../../Parent.Rnw')
@ ``

Just FIY, the header of the parent does not only include the latex info but also sources my main `.R` file with the calculations.

Anyway, if someone experience a similar problem try to add `cache.rebuild=T` to your included script(s).